# Problema ao filtrar concelhos por o distrito selecionado com ng-change no angularjs?

Tags: php, angularjs

Tenho um app móvel onde tenho dois `select option` (distritos e concelhos). O que pretendo é que ao escolher um distrito apareça só os concelhos que pertencem aquele distrito.

Como posso fazer isso? Já tentei filtrar pelo `ng-change` só que que não está aparecendo o nome dos concelhos aparece a lista em branco e pelo console consigo verificar que filtra.

**View**

```
<div ng-controller="FiltraEstabelecimentos">
        <form ng-submit>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <label ng-controller="ListaDistritos" style="border-radius: 10px; margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;" class="item item-input item-select">
                        <div class="input-label">
                            Distrito
                        </div>
                        <select ng-controller="ListaConcelhos" ng-model="distrito" ng-options="lista_distritos as lista_distritos.titulo for lista_distritos in distritos" ng-change="id_distrito()"></select>
                    </label>
                    <label ng-controller="ListaConcelhos" style="border-radius: 10px;" class="item item-input item-select">
                        <div class="input-label">
                            Concelho
                        </div>
                        <select ng-model="concelho" ng-options="lista_concelhos as lista_concelhos.titulo for lista_concelhos in concelhos"></select>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="margin:0px 10px 0px 10px;">
                <button type="submit" ng-click="filtra_estabelecimentos(input)" style="background-color: #CA5B60; border:#CA5B60; border-radius: 10px;" class="button button-block button-positive">
                    <i class="ion-search"></i> Pesquisar
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>  
    </div>
```

**PHP distritos**

```
function converte($term, $tp) {
    if ($tp == "1") $palavra = strtr(ucwords(strtoupper($term)),"àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùüúþÿ","ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÜÚÞß");
    elseif ($tp == "0") $palavra = strtr(ucwords(strtolower($term)),"ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÜÚÞß","àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùüúþÿ");
    return $palavra;
}

$distritos = array();

$sql = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM distritos ORDER BY titulo");
$sql->execute();
$distritos = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($distritos as $rows ) {
    $distritos[] = array(
        'titulo'        => converte($rows['titulo'], 0),
    );
}
echo json_encode($distritos);
```

**PHP Concelhos**

```
 function converte($term, $tp) {
    if ($tp == "1") $palavra = strtr(ucwords(strtoupper($term)),"àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùüúþÿ","ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÜÚÞß");
    elseif ($tp == "0") $palavra = strtr(ucwords(strtolower($term)),"ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÜÚÞß","àáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùüúþÿ");
    return $palavra;
}

$concelhos = array();

$sql = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM concelhos WHERE id_mae = :distritos ORDER BY titulo");
$sql->bindParam(':distritos', $_GET['id_distrito'], PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$sql->execute();
$row = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($row as $rows ) {
    $concelhos[] = array(
        'titulo'        => converte($rows['titulo'], 0),
    );
}
echo json_encode($concelhos);
```

**Controller Distritos e Concelhos**

```
.controller('ListaDistritos', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_distritos.php").success(function (data) {
        $scope.distritos = data;
    });
})
.controller('ListaConcelhos', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
    $scope.id_distrito= function (){
        $http.get("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_concelhos.php?id_distrito="+$scope.distrito.id).success(function (data) {
            $scope.concelhos = push(data);
        });
    };
})
```

Comment: Já tentou efetuar a consulta dos conselhos no change do combobox do distrito?

Comment: Não está faltando o `where` aqui `SELECT * FROM concelhos ORDER BY titulo`, seria isso?

Comment: Não, e nao sei como posso fazer se publicar uma resposta agradecia de como poderia fazer ?

Comment: O não é pros dois comentarios ou só meu? xD

Comment: e para o  Emir Marques

Comment: Emir Marques fiz uma alterações com o ng-change ja pus o codigo acima so que não apare os concelhos quando seleciono um distrito deve estar a faltar alguma coisa

Comment: Veja se ajuda, http://stackoverflow.com/a/15688483/1342547

Comment: Testei mas nao funcionou continua igual

Answer (score 1):

Para listar os concelhos conforme os distrito selecionado, é necessário adiciona um `WHERE` que especifique isso.

```
$sql = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM concelhos 
                          WHERE id_distrito = :distritos ORDER BY titulo");

$sql->bindParam(':distritos', $distritos, PDO::PARAM_INT); ;
```

Comment: Sim e agora como obtenho o id do distrito selecionado ?

Comment: @CésarSousa, antes da consulta faça um `print_r($_GET)` vai mostrar os nomes dos campos enviados, coloca aqui nos comentários.

Comment: Não mostra nada

Comment: @CésarSousa `print_r($_POST);` mostra algo? vc está vendo no console do navegador?

Comment: Da isto no console `Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Comment: Mas eu nao carrego em nenhum botão para filtrar eu quero que ao selecionar o distrito nos concelhos so apareça os concelhos daquele distrito